# Parse time and convert to minutes

Tags: r, time

Data looks like this.

```
data$arrival_time: int  1245 1345 1805 1950 710 755 2115 2215 615 730 ...
data$real_time   : int  1256 1423 1859 2105 712 1009 2139 2344 542 946 ...
```

For example, 1245 means 12:45 and 1345 means 13:45.

And I just want to convert 12:45 to 765 and 13:45 to 825, so it can be converted `format(hour:minutes)` to minutes. (cf. 12*60+450=765 and 13*60+45=825)

How can I convert time to minutes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modular arithmetic is your friend here. Two helpful R operators:

- `%/%` does integer division, e.g. `5 %/% 2` is 2 and `38 %/% 3` is 12
- `%%` is the modulo/remainder opeartor, e.g. `5 %% 2` is 1 and `38 %% 3` is 2

For positive integers where `m<n`, we always have `n = m*(n %/% m) + n %% m`.

We can use that to help by recognizing the "hour" part of your input is given by `x %/% 100`, while the "minute" is given by `x %% 100`, so your answer is:

```
60 * (x %/% 100) + ( x %% 100 )
#    ^ hours   ^   ^ minutes  ^
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. And May I ask another question for you?

Comment: I mean... I'd like to convert the date to weeks. For example the date data looks like 20130101 and I just want to convert this data to 1. (cf. date -> week for 53)

Comment: @hyejuryu this is a different question entirely and you might try asking it. In this case, you're best off parsing it as a date (see `?as.Date` or `strptime`) and then using some formatting options (see `?format.POSIXlt`) to convert it to week. It looks like you want the ISO week -- some packages like `data.table` and `lubridate` have built in functions to assist with that.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `floor` and `%%`.

```
v <- c(1245, 1345, 1805, 1950, 710, 755, 2115, 2215, 615, 730, 000)

floor(v/100)*60 + v %% 100
# [1]  765  825 1085 1190  430  475 1275 1335  375  450    0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try a mathematical approach, i.e.

```
x <- c(1245, 1345, 710, 2115, 542, 946)

(floor(x / 100) * 60) + (x - round(x, -2))
#[1]  765  825  430 1275  342  586
```